# Hook function call in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

is there a way to hook function call or redefine a function before a call in node.js? I need this for unit testing, may be Proxy or some testing libary is and option?

Example:

```
//some js file
function a(){
 b()// need to be hooked
} 

function b(){
  //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: you should take in an arg into `a()`....for example `function a(b){ b() }`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a wrapper around the target function, and perform whatever operations you need to do before execution, ex:

```
const tmp = b
function b {
  doSomething()
  maybeBroadcastAnEvent()
  tmp() //run original function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply()` with the `arguments` object to forward the call data of `a` into the `b` function.

```
function a(){
 return b.apply(this, arguments)
} 

function b(){
  //do some stuff
}
```

So whatever `this` value and arguments were given to `a` will be forwarded to `b`, and whatever `b` returns will be returned by `a`.

---

As it seems you attempted in your newer question, you can create a function that binds `b` to the `Function.prototype.call` method to accomplish this more succinctly.

```
var a = Function.call.bind(b);

function b(){
  //do some stuff
}
```

Now when `a` is invoked, the first argument provided will become the `this` value of `b` and the rest of the arguments provided will become the regular arguments of `b`.

---

If you don't care about the `this` value, and just want to pass on all the args, you can bind `null` as the first argument to `.call`, so that `b` will just get forwarded all the provided arguments as regular args.

```
var a = Function.call.bind(b, null);

function b(){
  //do some stuff
}
```